# Resizing controls when resizing jquery dialog box

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 controls in my div, one of which is a textarea. I am using the div as a dialog box.  When I resize the dialog box, I want to resize the textarea.  I am using the code, but it`s not working. Help please.

```
  <td>@Html.TextArea("myBox", new {@style = "height:X;width:X;"})
    </td>

$('#editDiv').dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true, buttons: { "Done": function () {  });
```

---

```
<div id="editDiv"> <table><td>@Html.Text("text1")</td><td>@Html.Text("text2")</td><td>@Html.TextArea("comments", new { @maxlength = 5})</td></table></div>
```

---

I have tried the following, which isn`t working:

```
.#editDiv table
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.#editDiv tr
{
    height: 100%;
}
.#editDiv TextArea
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to css

```
#dialogBoxId textarea
{
  width:95%;
}
```

Comment: The code isn`t working.  Please see my code, edited in the above